# How to cancel call to oracle stored procedure?

Tags: java, oracle

I have a java application, which searches for some records in oracle on click of search button. It calls stored procedures to search the data in oracle tables. Sometimes the search output is very large and takes a lot of time to process, I want to implement a cancel button so that the operation can be cancelled at any time. I thought of implementing separate thread in java but it wont solve the problem because the stored procedure is already called.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376615/how-is-oracles-jdbc-query-timeout-implemented

Answer (score 3):

You should create another stored procedure which contains **kill** command to cancel running store procedure and call this new SP from your cancel button.

For killing running SP refer this:

[How to terminate Oracle procedures which is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422113/how-to-terminate-oracle-procedures-which-is-running)